# How to store -00:00 time zone value in snowfkale

Tags: sql, oracle, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I had a scenario in storing the data reading from source file to snowflake table:

Input data line:

```
3 AC  0060876543NOV221080123 23 5 7 56709000900+0900
```

I have to read the last four digit in "09:00" format based on the plus or minus symbol. If the data coming as -0900 then in snowflake it should store as "-09:00".

```
SELECT                             
(CASE SUBSTR(raw_data, 48, 1) 
 WHEN '-' THEN CONCAT('-' , SUBSTR(raw_data,49,2) , ':' , SUBSTR(raw_data,51,2))
 ELSE CONCAT(SUBSTR(raw_data,49,2) , ':' , SUBSTR(raw_data,51,2)) END) + 
 (CASE SUBSTR(raw_data,40,4)  WHEN '2400' THEN 24 ELSE 0  END)  
AS COLUMN_1
FROM
    (SELECT  temp_row.$1 as raw_data  from
           @JOB_MANAGEMENT.SNOWFALKE (file_format => 'DB.TBL_FILE_FORMAT',
            pattern=>'.*/input_file.txt') temp_table) temp;
```

But, I'm getting error as below :

```
For minus value : Numeric value '-04:00' is not recognized
For plus value: Numeric value '09:00' is not recognized
```

**UPDATED:**

This is my teradata sql:

```
select (case '-' when '-' then '-' ||'04' || ':' ||'00'
else '04' || ':' ||'00'
end (Interval hour to minute)) +
 (case
    '2400' when '2400' then 24
    else 0
end (interval hour));
```

**output : -04:00**

```
select (case '-' when '-' then '-' ||'04' || ':' ||'00'
else '04' || ':' ||'00'
end (Interval hour to minute)) +
 (case
    '1835' when '2400' then 24
    else 0
end (interval hour));
```

**output: 20:00**

I want to implement the same in snowflake and thus in the second case statement it is throwing error.
The final column which I need to store the content in varchar column.

Comment: What data type are you using to store this? It seems numeric based on the error. Change it to varchar.

Comment: The column is of varchar type, but its not storing.

Comment: Your issue is caused by the + between the cases, it is considered an arithmetic operation and indeed '09:00' is varchar so this fails. Is it basically the same as doing **select 'a' + 'b';** which would give me **Numeric value 'a' is not recognized** since internally we try to cast the value to number. What are you trying to do with the + sign in between?

Comment: Thanks for the update, i have update the teradata query for the understanding of the **'a' + 'b'** statement, the same needs to take care in snowflake side.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTR(raw_data, LEN(raw_data)-5,3) || ':' || RIGHT(raw_data,2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: It takes the last 5 characters of the string and inserts a “:” before the last 2 characters. i.e. it converts “-0900” to "-09:00" which appears to be what the questioner asked